# Web Service with optional key,value map with camel?

Tags: java, web-services, dictionary, apache-camel

Having the WSDL:

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://MyWebService/" name="MyWebService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://MyWebService/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8081/MyWebService?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="doIt">
        <part name="Word" type="xsd:string"/>
        <part name="SomeParameters" type="tns:MapWrapper"/>
    </message>
    <message name="doItResponse">
        <part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="MyWebService">
        <operation name="doIt" parameterOrder="Word SomeParameters">
            <input message="tns:doIt"/>
            <output message="tns:doItResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
...
</definitions>
```

and the associated xsd:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://MyWebService/">
    <xs:complexType name="MapWrapper">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="map">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="key" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

What would be the best/easiest way to publish this WebService in order to get the input parameters of the WS to work with. Route should look like: (1) WS -> (2) InputParameters -> (3) some processing steps with the inputParameters -> (4) something depending on parameters from (2).

I tried to get the knowledge from camel-example-cxf; but there a lot of things mixed together making it hard to understand imo.

Some Java DSL code snippet would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make the Camel routes using `Spring`. For example: if you would create your custom bean and want to modify your message before routing it to actual endpoint you could do something like this:

```
public class CustomProcessor {

    public void processDoIt(Exchange exchange) {
        DoIt smth = exchange.getIn().getBody(DoIt.class); //Your message's body              
    }

}
```

And Camel route using Spring:

```
<bean id="processor" class="your.custom.CustomProcessor"/>

<camel:camelContext trace="true" id="camelContext" >

    <camel:route id="camelRoute">
        <camel:from uri="cxf:bean:yourWebServiceListenerEndpoint?dataFormat=POJO&amp;synchronous=true" />
        <camel:choice>
            <camel:when>
                <camel:simple>${headers.operationName} == 'doIt'</camel:simple>
                <camel:bean ref="processor" method="processDoIt"/>
            </camel:when>
        </camel:choice>
        <camel:to uri="cxf:bean:yourWebServiceTargetEndpoint"/>
    </camel:route>

</camel:camelContext>
```

Depending on the operation name camel will route the message to the corresponding processor. Also you can route your message elsewhere. It is up to you. It is just an example how it could be done.

**See also:**

- [Using Spring to configure the CamelContext](http://camel.apache.org/spring.html)
- [Camel CXF Component](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html)

Comment: The operationName would always be doIt. Just the inputParameters of doit operation would "decide which route to take".